# Error: Invalid value "sasl_ssl" for configuration property "security.protocol"

Tags: apache-kafka, message-hub

I'm using node-rdkafka to connect to IBM MessageHub with the following options:

```
var options = {
  // 'debug': 'all',
  'metadata.broker.list': brokers,
  'security.protocol': 'sasl_ssl',
  'ssl.ca.location': '/etc/ssl/certs',
  'sasl.mechanisms': 'PLAIN',
  'sasl.username': username,
  'sasl.password': password,
  'api.version.request': true,
  'broker.version.fallback': '0.10.2.1',
  'log.connection.close': false,
  'dr_msg_cb': true
}
```

The client is running on IBM Kubernetes Service pod (Ubuntu).
Please advice.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means you were missing some dependencies (SSL or SASL) when you installed/built node-rdkafka.

On ubuntu make sure you have `libsasl2-dev`, `libsasl2-modules` and `libssl-dev` installed.

You can check our [node-rdkafka sample Dockerfile](https://github.com/ibm-messaging/event-streams-samples/blob/master/kafka-nodejs-console-sample/Dockerfile) for a working example.