# Error: Invalid value "sasl_ssl" for configuration property "security.protocol")

Tags: go, apache-kafka, centos7, librdkafka

When trying to connect to kafka consumer ( kafka_2.11-2.0.0 in Centos ) using golang, getting below error :

```
[ 2019_12_12_12:45:05 ] ---->  Kafka Consumer Connection Error (kafka.Error=Invalid value "sasl_ssl" for configuration property "security.protocol")
```

**Code:**

```
consumer, err = kafka.NewConsumer(&kafka.ConfigMap{
    "bootstrap.servers": "example.window.net:9093",
    "group.id":          "my-Group",
    "auto.offset.reset": "earliest",
    "sasl.mechanisms":   "PLAIN",
    "security.protocol": "sasl_ssl",
    "sasl.username":     "test",
    "sasl.password":     "test",
})
if err != nil {
    fmt.Sprintf("Kafka Consumer Connection Error", err)
}
```

Implemented [kafka error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52674088/error-invalid-value-sasl-ssl-for-configuration-property-security-protocol) but no use.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

when librdkafka library was built without SSL support this error will come.
On Centos you will need the openssl-devel package installed prior to configure.
refer [solution](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/issues/411)